# ASP.Net Web Application Request.Params["AUTH_USER"] is empty string

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I'm building an ASP.Net 4.5 Web Application in Visual Studio 2012. I've put the following code in my Global.asax.cs:

```
protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["LastError"] = "";
        // Code that runs when a new session is started
        string delimStr = @"\";
        char[] delimiter = delimStr.ToCharArray();
        string[] requestor = Request.Params["AUTH_USER"].ToString().Split(delimiter, 2);
        string requestorEID = requestor[1];
        Session["UserID"] = requestorEID;

        //Get User data (name, roleid, rolename) from database
        List<SqlParameter> paramList = new List<SqlParameter>();
        paramList.Add(new SqlParameter("@EmployeeID", requestorEID));
        DataTable dtUserList = KLClassLibrary.KLDataAccessLayer.ExecuteSelect("GetUserData", paramList, "OffSiteCN");

        if (dtUserList.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            Session["EmployeeName"] = dtUserList.Rows[0]["EmployeeName"].ToString();

        }
        else
        {
            Session["LastError"] = "You Are Not Authorized To Access This Application";
            Session["EmployeeName"] = "";
            Response.Redirect("~/ErrorPage.aspx");
        }
    }
```

Whenever my code gets to the line

```
string[] requestor = Request.Params["AUTH_USER"].ToString().Split(delimiter, 2);
```

Request.Params["AUTH_USER"] is equal to an empty string. I've used this code successfully for years, although I'm new to VS2012 and .Net 4.5. What's wrong?

Comment: Were you using it in Session_Start always?  If so I would think that you must have had the user authenticated before the session start, which might have been in web.config.  If that is the case, what IIS version were you using before, perhaps IIS 6?  In IIS 7+ there are settings that need to be set in system.webServer that you probably have in system.web.

Comment: Thanks very much! I've always put this code in Session_Start. I have authentication mode set to Windows in the web.config. I'm not using IIS, I'm using the web server built into VisualStudio 2012 to launch my application. It keeps failing because AUTH_USER is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a complete solution, but I was able to create a workaround by using the following code:

```
string requestor = Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name.ToString();
        int requestor_length = requestor.Length;
        string requestorEID = requestor.Substring(requestor_length - 5, 5);
        Session["UserID"] = requestorEID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have "Windows Authentication" enabled in the project's properties (it is the very bottom of the properties list).  This will allow IISExpress to use windows authentication.

Then ensure you have denied access to anonymous users in your web.config's system.web authorization section, system.webServer or both.

For IIS 6.5 or below:

```
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <deny users="?"/>
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

For IIS 7 or above

```
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <authorization>
      <add accessType="Deny" users="?"/>
    </authorization>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

you can also set the windows authentication modes in these sections, but the server must allow you to override their default setting.  IISExpress is not set to allow this value to be overridden so you can not try to set it here for your debug mode.

The older versions of Visual Studio used Cassini to emulate a web server for your debugging.  Now it uses IISExpress, which will deliver you a closer experience to a true IIS server.  There used to be certain scenarios that would differ between Cassini and your actual IIS server - now it is rare to non-existent that I run into these issue.  However with correct configuration settings you can get your AUTH_USER value on session start.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this information! I've added the IIS 7 authorization section to my Web.config, but I don't see anything in the project's properties about Windows Authentication. I've looked on the Properties Tab and the Properties Page. I've also gone to the Properties section under Solution Explorer in Visual Studio and looked in the pubxml file under PublishProfiles and in the AssemblyInfo.cs file. What am I missing? Again, thank you!

Comment: I added an image of the property I was discussing.  This is not your fault, there is a different properties window that pops up if you right click and choose properties.  So you need to have the "properties" window already opened and then just select the website project.

Comment: I think I see the problem - you're talking about a web site project, but I'm talking about a web application project. At least, I see the properties you're talking about when I create a web site project, but definitely not when I create a web application project. Now, do you know how to solve my problem with a web application? Thanks so much for all the time you've put into this!

Comment: Admittedly I am not using 2012 - but in 2013 I am seeing the Windows Authentication in a WebApplication as well as a website.  I don't recall if it was 2010 or 2012 when IIS express was used instead of Cassini - I know Cassini is no longer an option in 2013.  Are you using Cassini, IIS Express or a local IIS when debugging?

Comment: In my project properties, under Web, I have Use Visual Studio Development Server chosen, which I believe is Cassini. At any rate, if I change it to Local IIS Web Server (use IIS Express is the default here), I do see the Windows Authentication property you indicated, but Request.Params["AUTH_USER"] is still an empty string. So I'm still stumped.

Comment: and you have entered the config change to deny anonymous users?